# how to get current page number when gridmvc is used in mvc application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing mvc application. I used grid mvc for index view. I want to pass current page number to controller when I click on page number of mvc grid pager.

Code for index view as below

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => 
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.Code).Titled("Code").SetWidth(400).Css("numbers");
                        columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Name").SetWidth(800);                   
                        columns.Add(c => c.City).Titled("City").SetWidth(400);
                        columns.Add(c => c.MobileNo).Titled("Mobile No").SetWidth(400);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Email).Titled("Email").SetWidth(400);

                        columns.Add().Titled("").Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(o => GridManageItemColumn1(o.Id).ToHtmlString());
                        columns.Add().Titled("").Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(o => GridManageItemColumn2(o.Id).ToHtmlString());
                    }).WithPaging(12).Sortable(true).Filterable(true)
```

How to get current page number using jquery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem,

I used code in view as below

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Epay.ViewModel.PurchaseOrderVM>

@using GridMvc.Html
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => 
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.Code).Titled("Code").SetWidth(400).Css("numbers");
                        columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Name").SetWidth(800);                   
                        columns.Add(c => c.City).Titled("City").SetWidth(400);
                        columns.Add(c => c.MobileNo).Titled("Mobile No").SetWidth(400);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Email).Titled("Email").SetWidth(400);

                        columns.Add().Titled("").Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(o => GridManageItemColumn1(o.Id).ToHtmlString());
                        columns.Add().Titled("").Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(o => GridManageItemColumn2(o.Id).ToHtmlString());                      }).WithPaging(12).Sortable(true).Filterable(true)  
  @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

In controller I returned List as below

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
 var skip = (page ?? 1);
 var take = 10;
 int POCount = POService.GetAll().Count();


var POList = POService.GetPoList((skip - 1) * take, take);
var PurchseOrderList = new StaticPagedList<PurchaseOrderVM>(POList, skip, take, POCount);
                    return View(PurchseOrderList);
}
```

and this code works for me.